# Place Map View above Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-mapview

I intend to place a map view below an image. The image is defined as the background for the Linear Layout. How would I be able to do so? As currently, the map view is on top of the layout and covering part of the image.

my code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/address_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pocket_one_map">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp" android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

    <com.esri.android.map.MapView    
     android:id="@+id/map" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     initExtent = "-200.6 20672.6 25000.4 52887.4"> 

    </com.esri.android.map.MapView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a  and within it take  and set below it 
like this

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:background="img"/ >

<com.esri.android.map.MapView    
     android:id="@+id/map" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     initExtent = "-200.6 20672.6 25000.4 52887.4"> 

    </com.esri.android.map.MapView> 

     </RelativeLayout>
```